# Failure to boot Ubuntu in a dualboot setup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I have dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS/Windows 10. Currently, it boots to `grub rescue`.

I was able to execute the commands up to `insmod normal` at [this site's](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux) commands for recovering from the `grub rescue>` prompt.

There I experience this error:

```
error: file '/grub/x86_64-edi/crypto.mod'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You might have just been bitten by the Windows 10 Anniversary Update bug. It may just have wiped out your Ubuntu partition. Boot a Ubuntu Live DVD and start gparted, and look to see if you **still** have a Ubuntu on an EXT4 partition. Cheers, Al

Comment: This seems plausible as I recently updated my bios, but hadn't had problems the first few times since. Still think so?

Comment: I don't _think_ this is BIOS related. Do the gparted thing and lets take a look at your partitions first. Post a screenshot in your question for me to look at. Cheers, Al

Comment: I ended up taking a circuitous route that involved rebooting through a BIOS interface to the original Windows install, which allowed me to solve the remaining problems. But thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-install the grub. Try this to see if it works. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2

But for me the best method would be using boot repair. It practically fix everything for you just follow the instructions.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Sadly this was the answer. Thanks, @jonathan-mounier!